# Change the browse view to show horizontally

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

On phpmyadmin when I browse a table all the tables are side by side (in a horizontal manner). I want them to be displayed vertically. I changed in my configs $cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'vertical'; but that didn't do anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. By setting $cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'horizontal'; in the config.inc.php the view will change once you restart your apache server, and refresh your cache (best method is to logout and log back in).